# Angular and desktop

Tags: angularjs, angular2

I'm reading about Angular on their website here:  https://angular.io/features.html, and I see the following:

> **Cross Platform**
>
> *Progressive web apps* - Use modern web platform capabilities to deliver app-like experiences.
>   High performance, offline, and zero-step installation.
>
> *Native* - Build native mobile apps with strategies from Ionic Framework,
>   NativeScript, and React Native.
>
> *Desktop* - Create desktop-installed apps across Mac, Windows, and Linux using the
>   same Angular methods you've learned for the web plus the ability to
>   access native OS APIs.

What part of Angular is this page talking about when it says that you can "create desktop-installed apps across Mac, Windows, and Linux"?  Does Angular have some built-in ability to generate desktop apps?  Or are they talking about using some 3rd-party framework like e.g. Electron?

Comment: Maybe they mean packaging a web app using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)? It allows for more desktop integration than a mere web app.

Answer (score 3):

The Angular framework can be combined with [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) or [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) to build desktop applications because both Electron and Ionic include the NodeJS framework which gives you the ability to access your desktop operating system using JavaScript.

Knowing the above, one can build desktop applications using Web technology (HTML, CSS, JavaScript).

[Here](https://robferguson.org/blog/tag/desktop-application/) is a helpful page with tutorials.

Comment: @loneboat - if you find this answer helpful, please mark is as 'accepted' and thank you.